# Why Mathematica does nothing with the expression Gamma[2 z]?

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

Could someone tell me why Mathematica just returns the input with this expression:

```
Gamma[2z]
```

> Gamma[2 z]

?

I expected this result:

$Γ(2z)=\frac{2^{2z-1}Γ(z)Γ(z+1/2)}{\sqrt\pi}$

Comment: Why should it? The right hand side is much more complicated than the left one.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Well I though it should compute the value of Gamma[2z] because in the 'rectangle that appears when you put the mouse in the command' says: Is the Euler gamma function of  $\Gamma (z)$

Comment: Yes, it is the $\Gamma$-function. But how on earth should Mathematica tell that you want to have the expression `Gamma[2 z]` expanded in exactly this way? For example, it could also return `Gamma[2 z - 1] (2 z - 1)`. Or any other identity involving the $\Gamma$-function (there are probably really many identities at least as interesting as the one you gave). What I tried to explain to you: i) Computers cannot read your mind and ii) Mathematica just doesn't work this way.

Comment: You can obtain the left hand side from the right hand side, though, because it is simpler (measured by some complexity function similar to `LeafCount`; look up `ComplexityFunction` for a few more details on the actual complexity function used). But for that you have to tell Mathematica explicitly to do so; try `FullSimplify[2^(2 z - 1) Gamma[z] Gamma[z + 1/2]/Sqrt[Pi]]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher why would I try `FullSimplify[2^(2 z - 1) Gamma[z] Gamma[z + 1/2]/Sqrt[Pi]]` ? It gives the LHS of the equality

Comment: Isa -- you ask why... one possibility would be maybe you weren't sure if you had the expansion correct. Then you could verify that `FullSimplify[2^(2 z - 1) Gamma[z] Gamma[z + 1/2]/Sqrt[Pi]] == Gamma[2 z]` returns `True`.

Comment: It's not a **command**. Don't think of it that way. It's an **expression**. *Mathematica* is an expression rewriting language. If you want it to rewrite an expression in a particular way, you must tell it.

Comment: @bills No, I was sure they are equal. I was just expecting the RHS

Comment: @JohnDoty I edited. How do I tell mathematica to give the RHS? I tried Expand[], Simplify[]. And gives the same: $\Gamma[2 z]$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issued raised is not really a problem; it is arises from the OP's misunderstanding of the result returned by Mathematica.

Comment: `Simplify` might give the answer you want with a suitable `ComplexityFunction`. `Γ[2z]` is certainly simplest representation of itself by the default criterion.

Comment: That rhs looks like gamma after she got run over by a reindeer...

Comment: ...for the same reason it returns `Sin[x]` unevaluated.  Why would *Mathematica* do anything other than that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use an undocumented internal function to for this purpose:

```
Simplify`GammaTuplicate[Gamma[2z], 2] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{2^{2 z-1} \Gamma (z) \Gamma \left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }}$

Another example:

```
Simplify`GammaTuplicate[Gamma[3z], 3] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{3^{3 z-1/2} \Gamma (z) \Gamma \left(z+\frac{1}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(z+\frac{2}{3}\right)}{2 \pi }$

Answer (score 12):

A top level way to *look up* the identity is through [`MathematicalFunctionData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MathematicalFunctionData.html):

```
identity = MathematicalFunctionData[Gamma, "MultipliedArgumentFormulas", 
  "IncludedSubexpressions" -> {Gamma[2 _]}][[1]];

Activate[identity[z]]
```

> ```
> Gamma[2 z] == (2^(-1 + 2 z) Gamma[z] Gamma[1/2 + z])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
> ```

---

An obscure way of getting the identity is to take backward and forward Mellin transforms and to mix in some hackery that prevent simplifications along the way:

```
Block[{Simplify`SimplifyGamma = # &},
  MellinTransform[MeijerGReduce[InverseMellinTransform[Gamma[2 z], z, s], s], s, z]
]
```

> ```
>  (2^(-1 + 2 z) Gamma[z] Gamma[1/2 + z])/Sqrt[\[Pi]]
> ```